# Unable to read png image using reportlab

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, reportlab

I need to generate a PDF file, which needs to insert some pictures
I searched a lot of information, but still can't read or insert pictures into PDF

The error message provided is:
UnidentifiedImageError:
fileName=<_io.BufferedReader name='111.png'> identity=[ImageReader@0x7fe50f6ba3d0] cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7fe50f46ad60>

code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPEqs.png)

Does anyone know how to solve this problem please?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: We need more information before we can help you. What are you trying to achieve? How are you doing it? What are you expecting that will happen? What is happening?

Comment: I want to use the reportlab suite to make a pdf file. I need to insert a picture file into this document, but I insert a png picture according to the way written on the Internet. It can’t be displayed. I’m not sure if I need to change the type of input data. 

_io.BytesIO? _io.BufferedReader name?